# I have to Iterate thorough check boxes if the value of checkbox is in my array I want the check box to be checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

This is my function and it is not working, My check boxes remain unchecked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var sales_agent_prev_arr = ['21-1', '21-2', '21-3', '21-5', '21-6', '26-1', '26-2', '26-3', '8-1', '8-9', '8-2', '8-3', '8-4', '8-5', '13']
        $('#user_type').on('change', function() {
          if ($(this).val() == 6) {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
              if ($.inArray(this.value, sales_agent_prev_arr) !== -1) {
                $(this).prop('checked',true);
              }
            });
          }
        })
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="21-1">View All</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="21-2">check</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant html code

Comment: Yes, sorry I added the relevant code now

Comment: You code works just fine when I run it. Please include the element with id `user_type` and place it all in the same snippet.

Comment: when  I console status of check box after $(this).prop('checked',true); I get true but I can't see the boxes get checked

Comment: Tamilselvan, as i said, please include all relevant code. Without it, we can't help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the two lines of your code , without them it works fine :

```
$('#user_type').on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 6) {
```

Comment: This is not an answer. I will bet that the op is using an element with the `id` of `user_type` but just haven't include it in the question

Comment: yes the user type is used for some privilege conditions I need this action to continue only the user is of that type